# Qt multiple UIs

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt project with two UI classes/forms.  The main class creates a second_window object and opens a second window like so:

```
second_window* sec_win = new second_window(this);
Qt::WindowFlags flags = sec_win->windowFlags();
sec_win->setWindowFlags((flags | Qt::WindowMinMaxButtonsHint) & ~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint);
sec_win->show();
```

The second window opens and displays just fine.  I am still able to interact with the main window, but clicking the main window does not bring it to the front of the second window.  The second window is always on top of the first.  Any idea how to change this?  I have researched all the Qt::WindowFlags and none of them seem to be what I need.  I have also researched alternatives to the show() method with no luck yet.

Comment: `QWidget::raise()` in case, if your widgets are non-modal. Or pass a `nullptr` instead of `this`/

Comment: changing "this" to "NULL" worked perfectly.  Thanks

Comment: Ok, duplicated my comment as an answer. You may accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QWidget::raise()` in case, if your widgets are non-modal. Or pass a `nullptr` instead of `this`. And don't forget to release widgets memory.